# Model Derivative API: Viewable unavailable

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am building a .NET app meant to extract the clashes using BIM360/Model Coordination API and then get the details of clashing elements using Model Derivative API, quite similar to what is done in https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-clashview (see the relationship diagrams under the link), just without the viewer.

I have succeeded with clash extraction, but am struggling with obtaining the model view object hierarchy. The root of the problem seems to be the lack of access to the view: while extracting the clashes, I collected the `versionUrn` and `viewableGuid` of the clashed model set document versions. Then, when I tried to use these 2 values in Model Derivative API calls (e.g. to call `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties`), I get 404 error, which I assumed is related to the fact that the given resource does not exist. This was confusing.

I started digging and extracted the list of available model views using `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata`: none of the available views had `viewableGuid` equal to the one that I was looking for.

Things got even more confusing when I queried the manifest of the version (`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/manifest`): it returned the view that I collected during clash extraction as a direct child of one of the SVF derivatives, but that view had further children, one of them belonging to the collection returned by the metadata query!

So in short:

- when extracting clashes, I get `versionUrn` and `viewableGuid`, the latter failing when used in Model Derivative API calls
- on metadata query I get a collection of `availableViewables`
- on manifest query I get a SVF derivative that has a child `viewableGuid` that has nested children, one of them belonging to `availableViewables`

I thought that maybe children of views use the same `objectids` as their parents, but unfortunately not: the viewer ids extracted from the clash results (`rvid` and `lvid`) do not exist in the child view.

**My question is:** what am I doing wrong? How can I access the object hierarchy of a model view specified by the `viewableGuid` collected during clash extraction? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response. I think you are correct that the manifest of  Model Coordination API does not tell metadata id of the model directly as Model Coordination coordinates the default {3D} view snapshot of the model versions. It focuses on the view, instead of the source of the view (svf/svf2) which is managed as metadata (with the id you are looking for).

I can raise a wish to ask Model Coordinate API also provides metadata id. As a workaround, you may try to search the general manifest of the model version.

```
//stands for one geometry node in the derivative
 var viewableGuid = 'a3186f12-7750-fa47-f60a-610a779ba5ac'
//stands for the id for explictly view within the geomtry node
 var viewableId = '24bb580c-5e74-4a65-bcae-e97c21424529-00027e16'

 var model_manifest =  <by GET:Manifest of the model version of Model 
  Coordination>

  var find_top_svf_derivative = 
   model_manifest.derivatives.find(i=>i.outputType=='svf2' 
  ||i.outputType=='svf' )
 if(find_top_svf_derivative){
      var find_derivative = find_top_svf_derivative.children.find(i=>i.guid 
   == viewableGuid)
      if(find_derivative){
          var find_metadata = 
    find_derivative.children.find(i=>i.mime=='application/autodesk-svf' || 
      i.mime=='application/autodesk-svf2')
     {
        //find the metadata id now
        //the source of svf/svf2 which stores the metadata
        var metadata_id = find_metadata.guid
      }
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Xiaodong Liang for the response. Apparently, I already had all the information you pointed me to, and it was not what I was looking for (at least I could not match the Ids from clash reports with anything coming out of the Model Derivative API).

I found the answer somewhere else, though: via Indexes API I was able to extract the properties of model elements belonging to the version underlying the viewable of interest. Among these properties, `lmvId` corresponds with the Ids stored in clash information. Solved! :-)